# Text comparison based on numbers/digits

Tags: python, text-mining

I would need to compare texts by extracting only numbers from the following two texts:

```
text_1="source="The previous low was 27,523, recorded in May 1900. The 1.35 trillion ($22.5 million ) program could start in October. The number of people who left the country plunged 99.8 percent from a year earlier to 2,750, according to the data from the agency."

text_2="The subsidies, totalling 1.35tn, are expected to form part of a second budget. New plans to allocate $22.5 billion to a new reimbursement programme."
```

However, it seems also to be relevant the next words (for example trillion /tn, billion). 
Do you know how I could get this information?

I have tried with

```
t_1=[int(s) for s in text_1.split() if s.isdigit()]
t_2=[int(s) for s in text_2.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

then to compare them, but it gives me not all numbers in texts.

Expected output:

```
differences

text_1: {27,523, 1900, 99.8, 2,750}

text_2: {}

common
    {1.35,22.5}
```

Comment: Your source text seems to use `,` and `.` in number as well as digits, so you'd want to include that (`.isdigit` won't suffice). Additionally, you already identified there's other text representing numbers, like `tn` and `trillion`. And finally, there's numbers that don't start after a space `$22.5 million`, or that don't stop before a space `27,523,` and `13.5tn`, so you have quite a challenge to extract numerical values from those texts. Your question is far too complex, please make it more specific.

Comment: I think I could manage tn, trillion, million with an if condition, but I would need to check the next two words (in order to include the space) after finding the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not impossible to it do the way you propose, but that is best achieved with regular expressions:

```
import re

text_1="The previous low was 27,523, recorded in May 1900. The 1.35 trillion ($22.5 million ) program could start in October. The number of people who left the country plunged 99.8 percent from a year earlier to 2,750, according to the data from the agency."

print(re.findall("\d+[,.\d]\d+", text_1))
```

In case you are not familiar with it, check [cheatsheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) and try it with [tester](https://regex101.com/). Once you got that, it is straight forward to get your expected output:

```
nums_1 = re.findall("\d+[,.\d]\d+", text_1)
nums_2 = re.findall("\d+[,.\d]\d+", text_2)

common_nums = []
for num in nums_1:
  if num in nums_2: common_nums.append(num)

print(common_nums)
```

Comment: No worries, mate. Substituting `,` for `.` is straightforward in a text like `12,4 34,6  98.78` , but in a mixed text like yours it is trickier. Basically I would do it in stages. First, extract all number like in my answer. Then replace `,` in each of them using `num = re.sub(',' , '.', num)`, then insert them replace respective numbers in the original text with those new ones. Maybe there is a better way to do it though.

Comment: Thank you @Aramakus. However, how I could change `,` into `.`?, I have tried with `nums_1 = str(re.findall("\d+[,.\d]\d+", text_1)).replace(",", ".")`, but it replaces also `,` in the list